# Did it possible to do proxy controller for uploading files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, webassembly, webapi

I want to implement file uploading from Blazor Wasm application.

User can upload file from Blazor Wasm application to cloud api.
Cloud drive is an external service and due to a security issues Wasm can't use custom headers while cross-origin request. And for me its mean that I need to send request to server controller and only after that send from controller action to external API.

But it means the file will be uploading twice. This is a terrible solution for me.
What I'm looking for some proxy solution when controller will instantly redirect action to external api without waiting until file chunk will be uploaded.

Same thing I need for downloading.
Something like that is possible because, for example, a video stream can be redirected instantly

Comment: Maybe you can use an HTTP proxy server which runs on the same domain with the WASM. When selecting a file to upload, WASM would make an HTTP POST request to the HTTP proxy server. It would then forward the request to the API. Which you can avoid the need to upload the file twice.

Comment: Using VPN is not acceptable solution.

Comment: What does `the file will be uploading twice` mean. Does it means it will request twice for uploading?

Comment: Its mean memory issues, controller upload ENTIRE chunk in memory and spend many time for that before do new request to cloud API. so instead to upload file once in reality file will be uploading twice! in controller and in cloud api.